# Reset consumer offset in kafka 0.10

Tags: apache-kafka

In 0.10 it seems we can reset the offset to a specific position with seek()

Short of writing code is there a command line util for this? It doesn't seem so, so far?

Comment: contrary to what it's name suggests, you can use the `kafka-streams-application-reset` script for non Kafka Streams applications `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh --zookeeper zk:2181 --application-id myGroupId --input-topics myTopic`

Comment: `kafka-streams-application-reset` only resets to the earliest offset position. It doesn't let you reset to a _specific_ position

Answer (score 2):

I've just implemented a simple command line tool for this purpose - https://github.com/serejja/kafka-offset-mgr.

Feel free to try it out and post issues/PRs if necessary.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I need.