# Kafka Consumer Group: read new messages only

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am using a `kafka-node` ConsumerGroup to read messages from Kafka. I want to read new messages from the topic, i.e. not all previously unconsumed messages but only messages that arrive after the creation of the ConsumerGroup.

The option `fromOffset: 'latest'`only comes into place when there is no stored offset for the given groupId. I can use this by creating a new groupId each time the ConsumerGroup is created, however I want to avoid this approach because this would create a large number of groupIds and stored offsets on the kafka server.

I also tried to manually set the offset to `-1` like this:

```
offset = new kafka.Offset(consumer.client);
offset.commit(groupId, [{ topic: topic, partition: 0, offset: -1 }],
  function (err, data) {
    logger.debug("tried to set offset: ", data);

    if (err) logger.error("error", err);

  })
);
```

This returns an errorCode of 0 which should be a success, but the ConsumerGroup receives old messages afterwards.

Kafka version: 0.10.0
kafka-node: 1.6.2

Comment: If this a new group, then there is no stored offset. If you want to reset the offsets for an existing group, you can use the reset command-line tool. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252704/reset-consumer-offset-in-kafka-0-10

Comment: Creating a new group is the workaround I choose for now. However I would like to reset the offset for an existing group and I am not sure whether this is possible via the kafka-node api and not a separate tool.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, can you not just set `enable.auto.commit` to false? Wouldn't that achieve what you want?

Comment: yes that seems to work, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initiating the kafka ConsumerGroup with options:

```
 autoCommit: false,   
 fromOffset: 'latest'
```

creates a ConsumerGroup that will never commit an offset to Kafka (unless you do it manually, which is not wanted). Hence it will always chose the 'latest' option when it is started.

Answer (score 0):

```
commit(groupId, payloads, cb)
```

The offset.commit's first argument should be groupId, not the clientId.

You should pass the consumer's group name to it.

Comment: thanks for your observation. however the clientId variable holds the correct groupId in my application. I changed it in the question to avoid further misunderstandings

Comment: do you use the consumergroup or Highlevelconsumer ?

Comment: I am using consumergroup

Answer (score 0):

Just small update for all those who had noticed that even with 'autoCommit' set to 'false' the solution mentioned above doesn't work and offset is still stored for group: please be sure to set additional flag:
**commitOffsetsOnFirstJoin: false** 
in option object. If flag is not set that offset will be stored per group and once started for the second time it'll get all messages starting from this offset

I hope it'll help to save (a lot of) time ;)